# How to read multiple Username and password from excel using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, JXLException, BiffException, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException { 

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\yirsh\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    Sheet s;

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\yirsh\\Desktop\\UAT WEBSHOP.xls");
    Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    s = w.getSheet(1);
    int z = s.getRows();
    System.out.println("no of Users:"+z);
    driver.get("http://...@...ip.../path/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //Thread.sleep(10000);
    for(int row = 1; row < 6; row++)
    {
        String username = s.getCell(2, 1).getContents();
        System.out.println("Username: "+username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_username_leftAside")).sendKeys(username);

        String password = s.getCell(3, 1).getContents();
        System.out.println("Password: "+password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_password_leftAside")).sendKeys(password);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[@class=' js opacity generatedcontent pointerevents']/body[@class='page-homepage pageType-ContentPage template-pages-layout-RexelHomePageLayout pageLabel-homepage language-de ']/div[@id='page']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='content-top-inner']/div[@id='content-inner']/div[@class='mid-wrapper'][1]/div[@class='yCmsContentSlot']/div[@class='login clear']/form[@id='loginForm']/div[@class='left sign-in']/button[@class='Sign-in rx-btn mb0']")).click();

        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Willkommen"))
        {
            System.out.println("Login Sucessfull");     
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Login Failed");
        }

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I have more than 10 user credentials but the code reads only one user credentials and exits please correct the code as per my need.As i am new for coding little bit confused of the `(int row = 1; row < 6; row++)` correct me the exact code

Comment: Selenium cannot read Excel, but [tag:apache-poi] can. Please fix your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If login is successful, you need to write logout code (I have put a comment). Also, you need to make use of row varibale. Also, put `driver.quit()` outside for loop.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, JXLException,BiffException,FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException{ 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\yirsh\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    Sheet s;

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\yirsh\\Desktop\\UAT WEBSHOP.xls");
    Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    s = w.getSheet(1);
    int z=s.getRows();
    System.out.println("no of Users:"+z);
    driver.get("http://RexelQAEnv:Rexel!23@52.19.191.249/aus/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //Thread.sleep(10000);

    for(int row=1; row <= 10; row++)
    {

        String username = s.getCell(2,row).getContents();
        System.out.println("Username: "+username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_username_leftAside")).sendKeys(username);

        String password= s.getCell(3,row).getContents();
        System.out.println("Password: "+password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_password_leftAside")).sendKeys(password);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[@class=' js opacity generatedcontent pointerevents']/body[@class='page-homepage pageType-ContentPage template-pages-layout-RexelHomePageLayout pageLabel-homepage language-de ']/div[@id='page']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='content-top-inner']/div[@id='content-inner']/div[@class='mid-wrapper'][1]/div[@class='yCmsContentSlot']/div[@class='login clear']/form[@id='loginForm']/div[@class='left sign-in']/button[@class='Sign-in rx-btn mb0']")).click();

        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Willkommen"))
        {
            System.out.println("Login Sucessfull");
            // write code for logout
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Login Failed");
        }


     }
      driver.quit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks working fine but i need to execute all the user if passed or failed.It should print the pass or fail message and should keep on execute all the users

Comment: its reading the 1st user credential and printing the result then it reads tbe 2nd username only and getting the below "errorException in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?"

Comment: Username: fullrightsuser1
Password: 1234567
Login Failed
**********************************************
Username: adminuser1
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that despite you are incrementing a `row` variable, you don't use it where you should to:

```
Sheet s;
// ...
for(int row=1; row < 6; row++) {
    String username = s.getCell(2,1).getContents();
```

Assuming that `s` is a `jxl.Sheet`, the second parameter of [`getCell` method](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html#getCell(int,%20int)) is the number of the row you are interested in.

So you may want to call `s.getCell(2, row)` there, since you have the row number in your `row` variable.